# Model items are empty

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET Core 3.1. Using EF, I have added my table models. Right now I am trying to implement login / register functionality. For this, I have an `AccountController` and inside that, I have created a `Task`

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Registar(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TblUser user = new TblUser
            {
                Username = model.Username,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Gender = model.Gender,
                City = model.City,
                Address = model.Address,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                Email = model.Email,
                Password = model.Password,
                PasswordHash = BC.HashPassword(model.Password),
                AuthKey = "a" + MD5.Create(model.Email),
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss")
            };
            _context.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Registration");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
}

// registration Page load
public IActionResult Registration()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Registration Page";
    return View();
}
```

Registration view model:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Mobile no not valid")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with database
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

`Registration.cshtml`:

```
@model RegistrationViewModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
@if (TempData["validationmessage"] != null)
{
    string alertType = "alert alert-" + TempData["alertType"];
    <div class="@alertType">
        <strong>Alert!</strong> @TempData["validationmessage"]
    </div>
}
</div>
<h2 class="text-center">Registar</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <form role="form" asp-action="Registar" asp-controller="Account" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Username" asp-for="Username" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." placeholder="Username">
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <input type="text" name="FName" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                <input type="text" name="LName" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." asp-for="LastName" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="Email" asp-for="Email" autocomplete="off" data-val="true" class="form-control input-sm" data-val-required="The Email field is required." placeholder="Email Address">
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Gender"></label>
                <input type="text" name="gender" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The Gender field is required." asp-for="Gender" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Gender">
                <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"></label>
                <input type="number" name="Number" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The PhoneNumber field is required." asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address"></label>
                <input type="text" name="address" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The Address field is required." asp-for="Address" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Address">
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="City"></label>
                <input type="text" name="city" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The City field is required." asp-for="City" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="City">
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Password" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." placeholder="Password">
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ConfirmPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" asp-for="ConfirmPassword" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="ConfirmPassword">
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="<removed for brevity>">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now when I am trying to register I am getting below validation errors

[image]

Although I have entered the `First Name`, `Last Name` and `Phone Number` but still I still get a validation error.

On debugging I have found

[image]

Comment: You have wrong name attribute on those fields in the form, they should match model property names. For example, FName should be FirstName

Comment: @YegorAndrosov yeah this was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of the `name` property  is **wrong**.

You should change the value of `name` property in `input` tag to **LastName** instead of **LName**.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" data-val="true" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." asp-for="LastName" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name">
    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Also do this for **PhoneNumber** and **FirstName**